# The time at which I can answer my question seems to be wrong

Tags: support, timestamps

I asked question, about 6~7 hours ago, now I found the answer to my question and I want to share this with others.
I tried to send the answer and got a message which says that I needed to wait 8 hours before I will able to answer my question, also there are noted a time when I will able to answer my question: 6:08 PM. 
I waited to 18:12 (6:12 PM) and see, still, I still getting the same message!

[image: bug]

Is there a bug or it's need to be so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Times on these sites are given in UTC, not your local time.

You can open the achievements dropdown box to see current UTC time; it is 16:28 UTC at the time of this writing:

[image: server time]

Comment: How I can change the time to UTC+2?

Comment: You cannot, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael by adding or subtracting 2 in your head. You cannot change what time the site uses or displays.

Comment: Thank you both, I got the point.